# How pkg is choosing its repos (FreeBSD 10)

Tags: package-management, freebsd, pfsense

I'm using pfSense, which uses a customised base of FreeBSD 10. `pkg -vv` shows the following relevant definitions:

```
PKG_DBDIR = "/var/db/pkg";
PKG_CACHEDIR = "/var/cache/pkg";
PORTSDIR = "/usr/ports";
REPOS_DIR [
    "/etc/pkg/",
    "/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/",
]
Repositories:
    pfSense-core: {
      url             : "pkg+https://pkg.pfsense.org/pfSense_v2_3_2_amd64-core",
      enabled         : yes,
      priority        : 0,
      mirror_type     : "SRV"
    }
    pfSense: {
      url             : "pkg+https://pkg.pfsense.org/pfSense_v2_3_2_amd64-pfSense_v2_3_2",
      enabled         : yes,
      priority        : 0,
      mirror_type     : "SRV"
    }
```

Looking at the two directories named in `REPOS_DIR`:

- `/etc/pkg` contains what looks like a default FreeBSD.conf (enabled=yes).
- `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos` contains a different FreeBSD.conf (enabled=no) and also a pfsense.conf that contains the two repo definitions reported by `pkg -vv`.
- There is also `/usr/local/share/pfSense/pkg/repos` which contains the same `FreeBSD.conf` and pfsense.conf as `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos` (the latter under a different filename though: `pfSense-repo.conf`), and also a link to further development repos in a separate file `pfSense-repo-devel.conf`.

I'm trying to work out the logic by which pkg chooses which of these overrides which others, especially since when a priority is given, in each case it's the same (=0).

Does a `/usr/local/etc/pkg/*.conf` file automatically override a similarly-named file at `/etc/pkg/*.conf`, if both are present? If not, what's going on and how is pkg choosing which repos to pay attention to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is actually all documented in the manual (q.v.).  `REPOS_DIR` is taken from `pkg.conf` and its directories are processed in the order given.  Files in each directory are processed in alphabetical order.  There's no notion of comparing filenames.  Rather, a file that is processed later overrides anything earlier that it conflicts with.

## Further reading

- [`pkg.conf`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg.conf).  §5.  *FreeBSD Manual*.  2015.